# fetch two URL in JavaScript (inside click listener)

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I want to use these two API but the second one don't work. These two are actually in a click listener.

```
 fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=' + coord.lat + `&lon=` + coord.lng + '&units=metric&appid=xxx')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        var tempValue = data['main']['temp'];
        var descValue = data['weather'][0]['main'];


        temp.innerHTML = "Temp: " + tempValue;
        desc.innerHTML = "Desc: " + descValue;
        //jamFactor.innerHTML = "Traffic jam: "

      })

    fetch('https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.2/flow.json?apiKey=xxx&prox=39.8485715,-86.0969867,10')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        var jfValue = data['RWS'][0]['RW'][0]['FIS'][0]['FI'][0]['CF'][0]['JF'];

        jamFactor.innerHTML = "Traffic jam: " + jfValue;
      })
```

Comment: @RahulKumar - How will that help if the second request "don't work" - it still won't work, it just won't work in series, instead of in parallel

Comment: Adding `catch()` method calls to both promise chains will probably help you identify the issue. I just tested the URL in postman and it also failed there. That means you are probably using the wrong URL or endpoint

Comment: The issue is that `fetch('https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.2/flow.json?apiKey=Lq0tUkmwnfryYX2J7gk9oBePCgfuGxpUa_0PTEsswaY&prox=39.8485715,-86.0969867,10')` isn't allowed in a browser, if you check your browser developer tools console, you should see an error regarding CORS

Comment: By the way, I'd remove those API keys you just published for the world to see

Comment: To be honest, I'd disable those keys and get new ones. Anyway, I see must've read the latest comment, so, by now you know why your second request fails - solution - make the request *through* your own **server** (or a cors anywhere type server)

Comment: @Yousaf the url works for me, also in the Browser!!

Comment: Then the issue is most likely related to CORS.

Comment: @Bravo tnx. I will make a new key :) its all about being a beginner

Comment: it IS a CORS issue - the fact that it "works in the browser" is meaningless, it doesn't work ON YOUR WEB SITE - because of CORS

Comment: Yes. its about CORS but I have no idea how to solve it. this is the inspect info: Access to fetch at 'https://traffic.ls.hereapi.com/traffic/6.2/flow.json?apiKey=xxx&prox=39.8485715,-86.0969867,10' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.